# How do I detect which '$or' clause each document belongs to in a query result?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, geolocation

I am trying to make a small market application with NodeJs and Mongoose.
I have a Market schema;

```
var Market = new Schema({
text: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
start_date: Date,
loc: {
    type: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Point'
    },
    coordinates: [],
}
});
Market.index({ loc: '2dsphere', start_date: -1 });
```

And I have 'docs' array. Each object contains coordinates[lon, lat], a radius variable in meters and a title.

```
var docs = [
{
    title : "Location 1",
    coordinates : [45, 50],
    radius : 120 
},
{
    title : "Location 2",
    coordinates : [15, 60],
    radius : 130
}, 
...]
```

I created a new query array which contains $geoWithin $centerSphere queries for all objects in 'docs'.

```
var query = [];
docs.forEach((doc) => {
    query.push(
        {loc:
            { $geoWithin:
                { $centerSphere: [ doc.coordinates, doc.radius / 1000 / 6378.1 ] }
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Finally, I want to get last 10 markets in these any geo center spheres. I run this query;

```
Market.find({ $or : query})
    .sort({start_date : -1})
    .limit(10)
    .exec(callback);
```

Query returns with last 10 markets in these geo centers, that's okey.

```
[
    { 
      text : "Market A",
      start_date : 2016-01-01,
      loc : { type: 'Point', coordinates: [a number, a number]}
    }, 
    ...
]
```

But my problem is, I want to know which location each result is included to. I want to add a location title to each result like,

```
[
    { 
      text : "Market A",
      start_date : 2016-01-01,
      loc : { type: 'Point', coordinates: [a number, a number]},
      title : "Location 1"   //like this
    }, 
    ...
]
```

Is there any way to detect this in a '$or' query? Something like; first document of result belongs to first $or clause, second document of result belongs to third $or clause etc. I hope I made myself clear. Thank you for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a easy problem. As there could be situation that more than one `document` will generate `Market A`, so one of possibilities is to check distance between  `document/location` and `market`, other one is execute query per `document/location` and tag every `market` with `location` data.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I think there is no easy way to do that.